# Minimize or maximize the powers

Tags: inequality, optimization

I came up with this problem and I could not find a proof. Basically the problem is, suppose positive numbers $a_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots,N$ satisfy
$$\sum_{i=1}^Na_i=1$$
then for $p>0$ when the expression
$$\sum_{i=1}^Na_i^p$$ reaches its minimum maximum? I tested using mathematica that it seems for $p>1$, $a_i=1/N$ gives the minimum, while for $p<1$, $a_i=1/N$ gives the maximum. Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: This is a special case of [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $p>0$, then by the inequality of power means (or using calculus), note that $f(p)$ is increasing in $p$, where 
$$f(p)=\left( \frac{\sum_i a_i^p}n\right)^{1/p}$$
so $f(p<1)\leqslant f(1)\leqslant f(p>1)$ with equality iff all $a_i=1/N$.

Comment: Note Jensen's inequality should work fine as well to show what you want, and has the added benefit of indicating when the other bound will occur.